# Not able to run ./gradlew assembleRelease command

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build.gradle

I am completely new to react native. I was trying to build an apk file out of react native application.

1.I went into android directory by cd android.
2.Then I typed ./gradlew  assembleRelease command.

It is showing me like this :
'.' is not recognised as internal or external command.

Please help me with this

Comment: try to run only "gradlew assembleRelease"

Answer (score 1):

are you sure you are in your android directory?
you can confirm by writing

> pwd

in your terminal